# How to calculate the odds of a 5x5 Bingo game?

Tags: probability

I don't have a mathematics background, but am trying to calculate what the theoretical odds of winning a 5x5 bingo game is if 5 numbers are drawn.

Eg board:

```
01, 02, 03, 04, 05
06, 07, 08, 09, 10
11, 12, 13, 14, 15
16, 17, 18, 19, 20
21, 22, 23, 24, 25
```

If each number on the board is a unique number, and numbers can be from 01-75, how does one calculate the odds of getting 5 numbers in a row diagonally or accross? I am not looking for the answer, but rather how someone goes about calculating such odds. Without any knowledge of stats, all I can think of is:

75*74*72*72 etc... 12 times. My thinking in this is that each space must have a number, and that that number can be anything from 1 - 75. There are 12 winning combinations, eg:

```
--A B C D E
1 x x x x x
2 x x x x x
3 x x x x x
4 x x x x x
5 x x x x x
```

One could win by getting everything in column A, B, C D, or E, or by row 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or the diagnals.

Yet somehow the odds being 1 in over a billion seem very off to me.

Comment: Are you intentionally making the rules different from how Bingo is played? In real Bingo, numbers in the first column are in $[1,15]$, numbers in the second column in $[16,30]$ and so on; and the centre square is free, i.e. has no number and counts as filled. Also, by "across", do you mean both horizontal and vertical? It sounds like just horizontal to me. And how did you arrive at "$15$ times"? There are $5$ horizontal, $5$ vertical and $2$ diagonal Bingo opportunities, for a total of $12$.

Comment: There are $\binom{75}{5}=\frac{75\times 74\times 73\times 72\times71}{5\times 4\times3\times 2\times 1}$ possibilities to draw $5$ numbers out of $75$.

Comment: Yes, it is intentionally different. But many thanks! @joriki

Comment: @Peter , many thanks! But does that account for the possibility that tot every combination of 5 numbers is necessarily a winning combination?

Comment: If only $5$ numbers are drawn, then there is no winning chance if some number is greater than $25$. And even if no number exceeds $25$, they will be virtually never lead to a win. The winning chance is actually $\frac{12}{17259390}=\frac{2}{2876565}\approx 7\times 10^{-7}$

Comment: By the way, if all numbers are in the range $1-25$, the probability of a win increases to $0.000226$, still very small!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Peter has pointed out in a comment, there are

$$
\binom{75}5=\frac{75\cdot74\cdot73\cdot72\cdot71}{5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}=17259390
$$

possibilities to draw $5$ numbers out of $75$. Your calculation didn't take into account that you can draw the numbers in any of $5!=120$ different orders.

If you were drawing $9$ or more balls, you'd have to take into account that more than one of the Bingo opportunities can be realized, but as you're only drawing $5$ balls, they're all mutually exclusive, so you can just multiply the chance of $1$ in $17259390$ by the number of Bingo opportunities. I don't know how you came up with $15$ for this, and I'm not sure what you mean by "across", but if you allow horizontal, vertical and diagonal Bingos (like in real Bingo), then there are $5$ horizontal, $5$ vertical and $2$ diagonal Bingo opportunities, for a total of $12$, so the probability of getting a Bingo with $5$ balls drawn is

$$
\frac{12}{17259390}=\frac2{2876565}\approx7\cdot10^{-7}\;,
$$

or slightly less than one in a million.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was a simple matter of how many people or rather how many cards have been sold in the game i.e. if `100` cards have been sold and you have just `1` card it will be `100` to `1` if you have `2` cards it will be `50` to `1`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE! Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

For a horizontal bingo, the odds of getting the right b number is 1 in 15, as it it for the I,n,g,and o.Wouldn't we multiply 15 to the fifth power? Ergo, one in 459,375